# Why does Perl's autovivification work in this case?

Tags: perl, autovivification

Can some one help me understand the output of this Perl program:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;
$hash{hello} = "foo";
$hash{hello}{world} = "bar";
print $hash{hello} . "\n";
print $hash{hello}{world} . "\n";
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

And the output:

```
foo
bar
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => 'foo'
        };
```

Where is the "foo" coming from?  How come it isn't printed out by dumper?

Note that if I swap the order of the assignments:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my %hash;
$hash{hello}{world} = "bar";
$hash{hello} = "foo";
print $hash{hello} . "\n";
print $hash{hello}{world} . "\n";
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

my output is what I expect:

```
foo

$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => 'foo'
        };
```

EDIT:
I know that `use strict;` would catch this, but I'm more interested in know **how** the string "foo" is still being printed.

Comment: Adding `use strict` should help to undestand this

Comment: When you say *Where is the "foo" coming from?*, do you mean **bar**?

Comment: No, I expected only the bar to be there, but I see now what is happening due to your nice answer (and Chris's comment) below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is missing

```
use strict;
```

```
C:\Temp> hui
Can't use string ("foo") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at 
C:\Temp\hui.pl line 7.
```

Make sure all your scripts start with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Given:

```
$hash{hello} = "foo";
```

`$hash{hello}` is **NOT** a hash reference.

```
$hash{hello}{world} = "bar";
```

treats the string `"foo"` as a hash reference and creates the hash `%main::foo` and sets `$foo{world}` to `"bar"`.

When you do:

```
print Dumper \%hash;
```

it only prints the contents of `%hash`. Whereas, when you do

```
print $hash{hello}{world} . "\n";
```

it prints `$foo{world}`.

Without `strict`, you do not get to find out that the script has trampled all over the package name space.

Add a

```
print Dumper \%main::;
```

or

```
print Dumper \%main::foo;
```

to inspect the symbol table after you run this.

Comment: Adding use strict finds problems with this, but it doesn't tell me how I am getting the output that I am.  This is more of a Perl internals question than a "plz fix my codez"

Comment: What's happening is it's autivivifying a variable called `%foo` (because that's what happens when you use a string as a reference). Add `print Dumper(\%foo)` to the end of your code to see the dangerous results.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the string "foo" is the only value of `%hash`, but (due to non-strictyness) %foo is being created that contains `(world => "bar")`

Answer (score 1):

If you were using strict, you'd get an error with your script.

> Can't use string ("foo") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ...

Answer (score 1):

Autovivification only works when the you start with undefined values. Since your `$hash{hello}` isn't an undefined value, you don't autovivify the next level. Instead, you end up using `$hash{hello}` as a soft reference.